# How can we do a sequential traversal of Neo4j graph?

Tags: php, neo4j, cypher

I am building a PHP web application and using Neo4j for graph representation.

The app allows one to construct pages representing parts of a product. Those pages are then strung together to form the hierarchy and order of the product's page components. The rationale is that when building more products, the user can reuse components (including sub parts) they already built for other products. Meaning, there is a many-to-many page to product relationship.

To represent this structure, a graph is appropriate. However, the issue remains how to allow end-users to browse a product sequentially. What i need is for each "current node" a user is viewing, to know the next and  previous nodes. This problem is not limited to siblings of a page, also to 
0..n-degree siblings (ie, siblings, uncle nodes, great uncle nodes, and so on).

I am able to represent a product structure easily enough using a series of simple **NODE-relationship-NODE** triples like so:

```
({id: 1000})-[:OWNS]->({id: 12})   // assume 1000 is a product node
({id: 1000})-[:OWNS]->({id: 13})   // with 12, 13 as its categories

// 12's descendant pages
({id: 12})-[:OWNS]->({id: 22})
({id: 12})-[:OWNS]->({id: 23})
({id: 12})-[:OWNS]->({id: 24})

// 13's descendant pages
({id: 13})-[:OWNS]->({id: 25})
({id: 13})-[:OWNS]->({id: 26})
({id: 13})-[:OWNS]->({id: 27})
```

The [:OWNS] relationship contains an 'order' property and an 'added' timestamp which together allow relationships between a parent and its children to be sorted in the desired order of consumption for child nodes in sequential navigation.

My goal is to allow the nodes of a product to be flattened and navigated sequentially in one of the views.

**Here's how this would work:**

An end-user begins navigation by selecting a product. Opening the product should show its first-level child nodes. Once a node is selected, the page content is displayed (this becomes the current node). The user then has the option to continue to the next page, without returning to the parent's menu by clicking a next button. Each page will show both a NEXT and a PREV button.

To navigate the hierarchy of a product (which could have multiple levels of nesting), we show the current node's first child, check for more children, and traverse them depth-first. When there are no more levels below, expected behaviour is to check for siblings of the current node to its right, when all siblings are consumed, i want to traverse back up to the parent, traverse its right siblings if any, and so on. I believe this is a depth-first traversal.

The same traversal would apply in reverse for "PREV" button.

From all my efforts, i have found it too complex to calculate the next/prev nodes on every page load. I have decided to pre-calculate a [:NEXT] relationship for all nodes and batch update this when changes in order are made during product creation or editing. I figure it does not harm if the navigation index is out of date for a little until it is recomputed.

The desired output, based on the example above is something like this:

```
// assuming OWNS.order = 0 for all 
// and OWNS.added = timestamp increases with each CREATE operation:
({id: 1000})-[:NEXT]->({id: 12})-[:NEXT]->({id: 22})-[:NEXT]->({id: 23})-[:NEXT]->({id: 24})-[:NEXT]->({id: 13})-[:NEXT]->({id: 25})-[:NEXT]->({id: 26})-[:NEXT]->({id: 27})
```

In other words, the nodes in sequence should be:

```
1000, 12, 22, 23, 24, 13, 25, 26, 27
```

It's easy enough to calculate the next item at the same level, under the same parent. But what i am finding difficult is a query that creates the following relationships:

1. A relationship between a parent (P_{i}) and its first (left-most) child (C_{0})
2. A relationship between the last (right-most) child (C_{n}) of a parent (P_{i}) and that parent's next right sibling (P_{i+1}).

And in the absence of a child or sibling, links to the level 1 or more steps up where the relationship can be found.

I am open to any suggestions, even without pre-calculation. Any ideas for how to think about this differently would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

*** EDIT ***

I have got this far:

```
MATCH (cur)

// Use optional matches because not all nodes will have these

// Match if has children
OPTIONAL MATCH (cur)-[rc:OWNS]->(child)

// Looking for next siblings, uncles, or great uncles. To do this
// i isolate the part of the pattern that might attach in between 
// ancestors all the way until the ancestor of interest (named parent) 
// which a suitable next sibling/uncle/great uncle/etc
// i want a reference to r and r2 so they can be compared.
// And note that rz has a 0 or more requirement, which 
// means potentially (cur) and (betweenparents) end up being equal
// and that (sibling) could end up being on the same level.

OPTIONAL MATCH (cur)<-[rz:OWNS*0..]-(betweenparents)<-[r:OWNS]-(parent)-[r2:OWNS]->(sibling)

// Condition is that the (sibling) node is considered "next to"
// the (current) node.
WHERE r2.order >= r.order AND r2.added > r.added

// Now order by first the current node's children if any as
// they have priority, then by the distance of the parent who has
// the suitable sibling/uncle/great uncle/etc, followed by, followed
// by the intended order of the sibling nodes (this puts at the head
// of the list the very immediately next item of both child
// and sibling) 
WITH cur, child, sibling, r2, size(rz) as depth, rc
ORDER BY rc.added, depth, r2.added

// Now can grab the head child element and head sibling element
// if either exists, which are (hopefully) guaranteed to be 
// ordered sequentially "next" of the current node.
WITH cur, HEAD(COLLECT(child)) as c, HEAD(COLLECT(sibling)) as s 

return cur.id, c.id, s.id
ORDER BY cur.id
```

Am i on the right track here? Or did i just over complicate something that should have been way simpler than this?

Also, i'm getting deprecation notice for naming the sz multiple relationship, which i need to label so i can order by increasing distance. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Based on your `NODE-relationship-NODE triples` example, what is the desired output?

Comment: I'd like something like this (assuming OWNS.order = 0 for all and OWNS.added = timestamp increasing with each CREATE operation):


  ({id: 1000})-[:NEXT]->({id: 12})-[:NEXT]->({id: 22})-[:NEXT]->({id: 23})-[:NEXT]->({id: 24})-[:NEXT]->({id: 13})-[:NEXT]->({id: 25})-[:NEXT]->({id: 26})-[:NEXT]->({id: 27})

or to make it easier to visualise:

  **1000**, **12**, 22, 23, 24, **13**, 25, 26, 27

Answer (score 0):

Alright it looks like i have a solution. Would be very open to anyone who knows how to optimise this or can poke holes in it.

What i reliased is that i can get stuck in a loop with my theoretical example which you'll see commented out below. It is critical to validate when reusing nodes with an [:OWNS] relationship, we do not have a second [:OWNS] relationship that leads to it higher in the map. Effectively, this gives two possible paths to reach the node and wreaks all kind of havoc.

First, let's start with a test graph. Below is not exactly valid syntax, but demonstrates the relationships reasonably:

```
MERGE (post:module{id: 21})-[:OWNS {order:0, added:1}]->(post:module{id: 25})
MERGE (post:module{id: 18})-[:OWNS {order:0, added:2}]->(post:module{id: 26})

MERGE (post:product{id: 1000})-[:OWNS {order:0, added:3}]->(post:module{id: 10})
MERGE (post:product{id: 1000})-[:OWNS {order:0, added:4}]->(post:module{id: 11})
MERGE (post:product{id: 1000})-[:OWNS {order:0, added:5}]->(post:module{id: 12})

MERGE (post:module{id: 10})-[:OWNS {order:0, added:6}]->(post:module{id: 13})
MERGE (post:module{id: 10})-[:OWNS {order:0, added:7}]->(post:module{id: 14})

MERGE (post:module{id: 11})-[:OWNS {order:0, added:8}]->(post:module{id: 15})

MERGE (post:module{id: 12})-[:OWNS {order:0, added:9}]->(post:module{id: 16})
MERGE (post:module{id: 12})-[:OWNS {order:0, added:10}]->(post:module{id: 17})

MERGE (post:module{id: 16})-[:OWNS {order:0, added:11}]->(post:module{id: 18})
MERGE (post:module{id: 16})-[:OWNS {order:0, added:12}]->(post:module{id: 19})

MERGE (post:product{id: 1001})-[:OWNS {order:0, added:13}]->(post:module{id: 20})
MERGE (post:product{id: 1001})-[:OWNS {order:0, added:15}]->(post:module{id: 23})

MERGE (post:module{id: 20})-[:OWNS {order:0, added:16}]->(post:module{id: 21})
MERGE (post:module{id: 20})-[:OWNS {order:0, added:17}]->(post:module{id: 24})

// These will cause a loop, and have been remarked out as invalid. 
// One would need to assert no such relations are created by checking
// for an existing shared ancestor of the two nodes being attempted 
// to be connected.

//MERGE (post:module{id: 21})-[:OWNS {order:0, added:18}]->(post:module{id: 12})
//MERGE (post:module{id: 18})-[:OWNS {order:0, added:19}]->(post:module{id: 10})

MERGE (post:product{id: 1001})-[:OWNS {order:0, added:20}]->(post:module{id: 16})
MERGE (post:product{id: 1002})-[:OWNS {order:0, added:21}]->(post:module{id: 22})

MERGE (post:module{id: 22})-[:OWNS {order:0, added:22}]->(post:module{id: 12})
MERGE (post:module{id: 22})-[:OWNS {order:0, added:23}]->(post:module{id: 21})
```

Now that we know what the test graph looks like, this code adds a [:NEXT] relationship for all nodes to the sequential next node, essentially a recursive "self-first" walk of the graph:

```
MATCH (cur)

// Use optional matches because not all nodes will have a valid next

// Match if has children
OPTIONAL MATCH (cur)-[rc:OWNS]->(child)

// Looking for next siblings, uncles, or great uncles. To do this
// i isolate the part of the pattern that might attach in between 
// ancestors all the way until the ancestor of interest (named parent) 
// which is a suitable next sibling/uncle/great uncle/etc
// i want a reference to r and r2 so they can be compared.
// And note that rz has a 0 or more requirement, which 
// means potentially (cur) and (betweenparents) end up being equal
// and that (sibling) could end up being on the same level as
// (current).

OPTIONAL MATCH (cur)<-[rz:OWNS*0..]-(betweenparents)<-[r:OWNS]-(parent)-[r2:OWNS]->(sibling)

// Condition is that the (sibling) node is considered "next to"
// the (current) node.
WHERE r2.order >= r.order AND r2.added > r.added

// Now order by first the current node's children if any as
// they have priority, then by the distance of the parent who has
// the suitable sibling/uncle/great uncle/etc, followed
// by the intended order of the sibling nodes (this puts at the head
// of the results the immediately next items of both child
// and sibling).

WITH cur, child, sibling, r2, size(rz) as depth, rc
ORDER BY rc.order, rc.added, depth, r2.order, r2.added

// Now can grab the head child element or head sibling element
// if one is not null. These are guaranteed to be 
// ordered sequentially starting from the "next" of the 
// current node.

WITH cur, HEAD(FILTER( i in COLLECT(coalesce(child,sibling)) WHERE i is NOT NULL ))  as s 

// Create relationship from cur to the head item child or sibling 
// that was found to be a valid next.
foreach(i in CASE WHEN s IS NULL then [] else [s] end |
    MERGE (cur)-[:NEXT]->(i)
)
```

[image: see graph result]

Once the relationships are added, querying the graph is easy for any current node's next and previous items. For example:

```
// TO QUERY THE previous, cur, next nodes
OPTIONAL MATCH (cur:post{id: 23})-[:NEXT]->(next)<-[:OWNS*0..]-(context:product{id: 1001})
OPTIONAL MATCH (cur)<-[:NEXT]-(prev)<-[:OWNS*0..]-(context) 
return prev, cur,next
```

Note the use of a (context) node to filter out paths that do not belong to the product being currently explored, but still allowing a product to import nodes from other products.

If you have any suggestions for me to improve this, i would love to hear them. I am sure this is inefficient, but it's my first time working with Neo4j and it's the best i could come up with. And it works. And it's going to be batch pre-calculated anyway and simply queried at run-time for next and prev nodes.